# No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/genius"}, missing required keys: [:cohort_id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin, nested-resources

I have an activeadmin rails 5 app that I am getting a no routes match error even though the routes are shown.

### Rails Routes

```
new_admin_cohort GET      /admin/cohorts/new(.:format)                               
admin/cohorts#new
                edit_admin_cohort GET      /admin/cohorts/:id/edit(.:format)                          
admin/cohorts#edit
                     admin_cohort GET      /admin/cohorts/:id(.:format)                               
admin/cohorts#show
                                  PATCH    /admin/cohorts/:id(.:format)                               
admin/cohorts#update
                                  PUT      /admin/cohorts/:id(.:format)                               
admin/cohorts#update
                                  DELETE   /admin/cohorts/:id(.:format)                               
admin/cohorts#destroy
 batch_action_admin_cohort_genius POST     /admin/cohorts/:cohort_id/genius/batch_action(.:format)    admin/genius#batch_action
admin_cohort_genius               GET      /admin/cohorts/:cohort_id/genius(.:format)                 admin/genius#index
                                  POST     /admin/cohorts/:cohort_id/genius(.:format)                 admin/genius#create
           new_admin_cohort_geniu GET      /admin/cohorts/:cohort_id/genius/new(.:format)             admin/genius#new
          edit_admin_cohort_geniu GET      /admin/cohorts/:cohort_id/genius/:id/edit(.:format)        admin/genius#edit
               admin_cohort_geniu GET      /admin/cohorts/:cohort_id/genius/:id(.:format)             admin/genius#show
                                  PATCH    /admin/cohorts/:cohort_id/genius/:id(.:format)             admin/genius#update
                                  PUT      /admin/cohorts/:cohort_id/genius/:id(.:format)             admin/genius#update
                                  DELETE   /admin/cohorts/:cohort_id/genius/:id(.:format)             admin/genius#destroy
```

I am trying to nest the User resource under the Cohort resource where i can co-create the user and the cohort or one cohort and multiple users inside of the one cohort (so far have not been able to do either)

### User model

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do 
belongs_to :cohort, :finder => :find_by_resource_key!#optional: true
permit_params :avatar, :name, :classroom_id, :first_name, :cohort, :last_name, 
:username, :email, :email2, :cell, :password, :password_confirmation, 
:stipend, :address, :benchmarks, :genius, :attendance_id, :users_id, 
:cohort_id, :city, :projects_attributes, avatar_attributes: [:_destroy]
config.batch_actions = true
menu priority: 4
duplicable?

controller do
 def find_resource
  User.find_by(resource_key: params[:id])
 end
end


  index do
    selectable_column
    id_column :cohort_id
    column :first_name
    column :last_name
    column :email
    column :email2
    column :username
    column :address
    column :cell
    column :projects
    column :sign_in_count
    column :created_at
    image_column :avatar, style: :thumb

    actions
  end

 form do |f|
  f.inputs do
   f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
   f.input :genius
   f.input :cohort_id
   f.input :city
   f.input :cell
   f.input :email
   f.input :password, input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" }
   f.input :email2
   f.input :username
   f.input :avatar, as: :file
  if f.object.avatar.present?
    f.semantic_fields_for :avatar_attributes do |avatar_fields|
     avatar_fields.input :_destroy, as: :boolean, label: 'Delete?'
  end
end
f.inputs 'Projects' do
    f.has_many :projects, allow_destroy: true,
                              new_record: true do |u|
        u.input :app_name
        u.input :coding
        u.input :project_details
        u.input :start_date
        u.input :github
        #end
       end
   f.actions
        end
       end
     end
   end
```

### Cohort model

```
ActiveAdmin.register Cohort do 
permit_params :city, :cohort_id, :genius, users_attributes: [:last_name, :users_id, :cohort, :username, :genius, :cohort_id, :city, :email, :email2, :cell, :stipend, :project], attendances_attributes: [:present, :absent, :halfday, :class_date], classroom_attributes: [:id, :body, :_destroy]

menu priority: 3
config.batch_actions = true
duplicable?
#active_admin_importable
sortable tree: true

form do |f|
  f.inputs 'Hgp Cohorts', :body
  f.inputs do
    f.input :city, label: "Office Location"
    f.input :cohort, label: "Cohort Number"
  end
  f.inputs "Geniuses" do
    f.has_many :users,allow_destroy: true,
                          new_record: false do |a|
      a.input :genius
      a.input :cell
      a.input :email
      a.input :password, input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" }
      a.input :email2
      a.input :username
      a.input :avatar, as: :file
      if user.object.avatar.present?
        uuser.semantic_fields_for :avatar_attributes do |avatar_fields|
         avatar_fields.input :_destroy, as: :boolean, label: 'Delete?'
      end
   end
  end
end
  f.actions
end
index do
 selectable_column
 id_column
 column :city
 column :cohort
 actions
end
```

Comment: The error is not about a missing route. It’s about a missing cohort_id.

Comment: Ok, the title is what the error says, not what i think the error is about. That being said, my question is the same, why am i getting this error?

Comment: Because you’re missing a cohort_id. If you look at your route for the index action, you need to supply a cohort_id for the route to work. The route is /admin/cohorts/:cohort_id/genius. The part with the colon (:cohort_id) has to be passed to the route for it to work.

Comment: that's my problem, I know where to pass it in a regular app but with activeadmin auto-generating routes, I'm not sure where to pass the cohort_id